# Python - Trying to make a Random String Generator

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a String generator based on how much length you provided and it gets the alphabets from 2 arrays , One provided for Maj and one for Min , so that's my code but it usually returns "b" or error

```
from random import randint
def randomstr(stringsize):
    Alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    Alphabet2 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    i = stringsize+1
    LocalRanDom = ""
    StringGen = []
    while i < stringsize+1:
        i = i-1
    MajorMin = randint(1,2)
    print(Alphabet[1])
    if MajorMin == 1:
        LocalRanDom = randint(1,26)
        StringGen.append(Alphabet[LocalRanDom])
    if MajorMin == 2:
        LocalRanDom = randint(1,26)
        StringGen.append(Alphabet2[LocalRanDom])
    return StringGen 

randomstr(3)
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: `random.sample(string.ascii_letters, n)` would seem more appropriate

Comment: Please add what error you get.

Comment: Also, you are not printing the return value, you are only printing Alphabet[1] which is "b" always.

Comment: Yeh right i removed the print Alphabet[1] now that's the end of script
         StringGen.append(Alphabet2[LocalRanDom])
          print(StringGen)
          return 
         randomstr(2)
Error :    StringGen.append(Alphabet[LocalRanDom])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @ŠhyštērĀņģeļ You really need to fix your indentation as the indentation in the pending edit is almost certainly not correct.

Comment: It seems like you need to indent `StringGen.append(Alphabet[LocalRanDom])` one more level but I'm not sure since you are still not corrected your indentation.

Comment: Please use **[edit]** to add all relevant data to your question. (As you still need to edit it to fix the indendation anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly unsalvageable but I'll go through it and explain all the issues I've encountered with it. You also didn't indent your code properly in your question so I've made some assumptions on that front.

### Addressing Code Issues

**Alphabet generation**

```
Alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]`
Alphabet2 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]`
```

These could be more succinctly expressed as:

```
lowercase_letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
uppercase_letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
```

**Iteration logic**

Your current implementation *will not iterate at all* because you assign `i = stringsize+1` and then create a while loop with the condition `i < stringsize+1` - *this will never be true when the condition is first evaluated*.

The correct and Pythonic approach would be to use a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(stringsize):
    ...
```

**String concatenation**

Strings in Python are technically lists but it's not really very pleasant to construct strings by appending individual characters to a list.

One approach would be to set `StringGen = ''` and then add characters to it using `StringGen += c` within the for loop. However, [this isn't efficient](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/). I'll provide a solution at the bottom of this post to demonstrate an implementation that does not involve concatenation within loops.

**Misusing integers for conditional logic**

The code:

```
MajorMin = randint(1,2)
if MajorMin == 1:
    ...
if MajorMin == 2:
    ...
```

Could be made far clearer using this equivalent logic:

```
use_uppercase_letter = random.choice([True, False])
if use_uppercase_letter:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

### Alternative Implementations

**Refined variation of your approach**

Here's a different implementation of `randomstr` that builds on the points here:

```
import string
import random


def randomstr(stringsize):
    lowercase_letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    uppercase_letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

    def generate_letters(n):
        for i in range(n):
            use_uppercase_letter = random.choice([True, False])
            if use_uppercase_letter:
                yield random.choice(lowercase_letters)
            else:
                yield random.choice(uppercase_letters)

    return ''.join(c for c in generate_letters(stringsize))


print(randomstr(10))
```

**My best crack at it**

This is a much more concise implementation that I'll offer in case you want it, but it deviates a lot from your original approach.

```
import string
import random


def randomstr(stringsize):
    letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase)
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(stringsize))


print(randomstr(10))
```

**Example runs**

These are the examples of the outputs you get with either of the implementations above.

```
MYXPupqiRG
ELNMPktrbe
ZnYBjlIxNQ
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This is not pythonic lol see Chris's comment

First of all , I have no clue what the i is for? you just have it to 
`i = stringsize+1` and then

```
while i < stringsize+1:
    i = i-1
```

after that, you never use it.

If you want a random String generator, you can do the following.

```
from random import random


def gen(length):
    string = ''
    for _ in range(length):
        shift = int(random()*26) # if you want cap letters, feel free to customzie
        asci = shift + 97
        string += chr(asci)
    return string

print(gen(3))
```

Comment: Nice one but i prefer the other one because the code hasn't changed alot :D